# Wrap teasers in a div (simple taxonomy page, no views)

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I would like to know if there is a way to wrap the nodes teaser in a  without using jQuery.

Basically, this is how the DOM is :

```
<div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system"> <!-- printed by the page.tpl.php -->
    <div class="term-listing-heading">
        term description, others custom fields…
    </div>
    <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
    <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
    <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
<div>
```

What I want :

```
<div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system"> <!-- printed by the page.tpl.php -->
    <div class="term-listing-heading">
      term description, others custom fields…
    </div>
    <div class="wrap"> <!-- put a wrapper here -->
        <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
        <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
        <div class="node-teaser">teaser content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Display Suite for a better customization, I checked all the tpl files, but I found nothing…

Thx :)

Comment: this might be helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/1869632

Comment: Thank you :) But it explain how to theme the inside of the node teaser (which is already very simple with Display Suite), not how to theme the wrapper of ALL the nodes teaser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using template.php and hook_preprocess_page()**

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes']['#prefix'] = '<div class="here-is-your-div">';
    $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
}
```

So what this does is checks if the URLs match the condition /taxonomy/term/%term-id then if it's satisfied then it adds a prefix and a suffix that are to be rendered by `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`.

Comment: Ah… I didn't know we could do that… interesting!
But it's wrapping the content, and the taxonomy term description and the nodes teaser are already in it. It's not wrapping all the nodes teaser. :s

Comment: Oh! I'm really sorry! I forgot that detail. I've updated my post already. :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad to help! :)

Comment: This prevented me from tearing out my hair in frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Like many other things in Drupal, why this isn't something that was accounted for is beyond me. Here's an alternative approach that seems a little cleaner to me than the accepted answer. I don't like messing with prefixes/suffixes, and it bothers me when I can't access a template directly.

Add some additional template suggestions to nodes based on view mode:

```
THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $view_mode = $vars['view_mode'];
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $view_mode;
}
```

Then you can have templates for 'node--full.tpl.php', 'node--teaser.tpl.php', etc., like it should probably do by default.